# Discrete Random Variables (Coin Flipping)

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Consider flipping a coin sequentially. Let the probability of seeing a head be p, 0 < p < 1.
Let N denote the number of times that the coin is flipped until the first time that two
consecutive heads or two consecutive tails appear.
How do we derive the probability mass function of N?

So I assume N should be at least 2 which means P(N = 2) = 2/4. [{H,H},{H,T},{T,H},{T,T}]

P(N=3) = 6/8. [{H,H,H}.{H,H,T},{H,T,H},{H,T,T},{T,H,H},{T,H,T},{T,T,H},{T,T,T}]

Is this correct? I'm not sure

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you tried to compute $P(N=4)$, for example?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: That cannot be correct as $\mathbb{P}[N=2]+\mathbb{P}[N=3]\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_n$ denote the event that the first time you get two heads or two tails is in n throws. Then $\mathbb{P}[N=i]=\mathbb{P}[E_i]\quad\forall i\in[n]$. Note that $\{E_2,E_3,\dots\}$ are disjoint.

As you pointed out, $\mathbb{P}[N=2]=\mathbb{P}[E_2]=\frac{1}{2}$. Now let us look at the other cases. We will look at $E_3$ in detail and then generalize. We hit $E_3$ only when $\neg E_2$. The first two flips for such an event are $\{HT, TH\}$.

Specifically, the last flips are $\{T, H\}$ respectively. If the last flip is $T$, then with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we can flip the third coin as $T$ for $E_3$, and in case last flip is $H$, then too with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we can flip the third coin as $H$ for $E_3$. In case this doesn't happen, we have $\neg E_2\wedge\neg E_3$, and we can try for $E_4$ and so on.

Since nothing we mentioned in the last case is specific to the third throw, this generalizes. In other words,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[E_i|\neg E_2\wedge\neg E_3\dots\neg E_{i-1}] &= \frac{1}{2}\\
\text{and }\mathbb{P}[\neg E_i|\neg E_2\wedge\neg E_3\dots\neg E_{i-1}] &= \frac{1}{2}\text{$\qquad\forall i\geq3$}\\
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[E_2] &= \frac{1}{2}\\
\mathbb{P}[E_3|\neg E_2] &= \frac{1}{2}\\
\mathbb{P}[E_3] &= \mathbb{P}[E_3|\neg E_2] \times \mathbb{P}[\neg E_3] 
= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{4}\\
\mathbb{P}[E_4] &= \mathbb{P}[E_4|\neg E_2\wedge\neg E_3] \times \mathbb{P}[\neg E_2\wedge\neg E_3] 
= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{4} =\frac{1}{8}\\
\end{align*}
In general, the required distribution is: $$\mathbb{P}[N=i] =\mathbb{P}[E_i] = \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}\quad \forall i \geq 2$$